# When entering Tokyo Bay, does the monster in Tokyo City take damage?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

For a 5+ player game, the first two players to roll fists/claws can enter Tokyo.  If there is already a player in Tokyo City, but Tokyo Bay is open, does rolling fists/claws damage the monster in Tokyo City as well as allowing entry to Tokyo Bay or do they only get to enter without dealing damage?

Comment: Thank you Steven for creating the king-of-tokyo tag for me. I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You deal damage to the Monster in Tokyo City, then take control of Tokyo Bay (or Tokyo City if the damaged Monster abandons it).**

From the [rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63033/king-of-tokyo-english-rules), page two far right column:

> If Tokyo Bay is unoccupied but Tokyo City is, the Monster who attacks Tokyo deals damage to the moster controlling it, then takes control of Tokyo Bay - or Tokyo City if the damaged monster abandons Tokyo City.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, attack damage is resolved before checking if you move into Tokyo (regardless of whether or not Tokyo Bay is available), so the monster who went into Tokyo first will take that damage. For example, if the monster already in Tokyo wished to yield, they could do so, and the second monster would go into Tokyo City instead of Tokyo Bay.

Comment: Thanks. We've always played that the second monster just gets to enter Tokyo Bay and doesn't deal damage but a new player asked about this and we couldn't find our rules. Nice to have the correct rules.